# Rounding Twice - into one rule

Tags: math, language-agnostic, rounding

I need to round a number by 1/32 and THEN round it by 1/100th.  I need to convert this into one single rounding rule though (using an archaic program...).  I can multiply and divide the original number and all that, just can't round twice....

Is there a way to do this mathematically?

Thanks!

kcross

Comment: It's a propitiatory language for this program.  Pretty similar to Java though.  It will allow me to do a rounding (ie I can tell it to round a number by 1/100) but it won't let me do sequential roundings... so I basically need to give it a single rounding rule, and convert the number somehow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If whatever you're using lets you define functions, the most readable implementation would be this:

```
function round(x, interval){
    //implementation left as an exercise to the reader
}

#rounds x by interval1, then by interval2
function doubleRound(x, interval1, interval2){
    return round(round(x, interval1), interval2)
}
```

but if all you have is simple arithmetic, you can unroll everything into one statement.

To round a non-negative number x to the nearest interval of N, you can use this formula:

```
round(x,N) = floor((x + (N/2)) / N) * N
```

to round twice, you nest the function within itself:

```
round(round(x, N1), N2) = floor(((floor((x + (N1/2)) / N1) * N1) + (N2/2)) / N2) * N2
```

so to round by 1/32 and then 1/100, you use:

```
floor(((floor((x + ((1/32)/2)) / (1/32)) * (1/32)) + ((1/100)/2)) / (1/100)) * (1/100)
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate.  What would floor do? (I'm not sure if there is a floor function tbh....)

Comment: floor takes a number and chops off everything to the right of the decimal point. for example, `floor(1.2)` returns `1`, `floor(17.9)` returns `17`.

Comment: Great, thanks.  I'm not sure if this program do floors (sadly)... It's brutal.  Thanks though